# Precision rounding after decimals

Tags: javascript, rounding

I need to round a number up to two digits, I'm currently using `toFixed(2)` but it doens't round it, I've Googled / Stack Overflow'ed but couldn't really find an answer for my situation:

```
const value = -0.004;
console.log(value.toFixed(2)); // 0.00
// Expected: -0.01
```

Anyone a clue? Keep safe.

Comment: `console.log(value.toFixed(2)); // -0.00`

Comment: `Number.prototype.toFixed()` rounds to the nearest integer/decimal. 4 is closer to 0, so it is rounded towards 0.00 instead of 0.01.